# ¿Como agregar id a cada botón del dataTable con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function trerDatos(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'controlador.php/?ajax=1',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    data:"",
    async: true,
    success:function(data){
      var contador = 0;
      $("#dataTable").dataTable().fnDestroy();
      $("#dataTable").DataTable({

        "aaData": data.DatoClien,
        "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "nombres"},
        { "mDataProp": "apellidos"},
        { "mDataProp": "usuario"},
        { "mDataProp": "email"},
        { "mDataProp": "documento"},
        { "mDataProp": "celular"},
        { "mDataProp": "fechaIngreso" },
        { "mDataProp": "fechaRetiro" },
        { "mDataProp": "estado" },
        { "mDataProp": "roll" },
        {"defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary sm' id='btnEditar_"+AQUI NECESITO ID+"'>Editar</button> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger sm' id='btnEliminar'>Borrar</button>","className": "text-center"},
        ],
        "bSort" : true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        language: {"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"},
      });
    },error:function(a,b,c){alert("Error");},
  });
}
```

lo que necesito es poder diferencia cada boton de la fila poder ejecutar la accion que seleccione

Comment: No necesitas un id para cada boton en cada fila.  Puedes diferenciar de donde proviene el click en el handler.

Comment: ¿tienes algún ejemplo, lo que pasa es que necesito llevarme los datos de la toda la fila a un modal?

Comment: DataTables tiene la opcion de cuando se haga click en la fila obtener los datos para ponerlo en inputs o lo que quieras con ellos. Por ejemplo tengo una app web que en un modal se crea el DataTable y cuando le hago click se llenan los inputs con la info de la fila. ¿Crees que esto te sirva?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Cperea te recomiendo que uses la siguiente estructurura para tu datatable:

```
<div class="tblWrap">
  <table class="table-striped tblHis">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombres</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Usuario</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Documento</th>
        <th>Celular</th>
        <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
        <th>Fecha Retiro</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Roll</th>
        <th>Acciones</th> // aqui iran tus botones
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

con la estructura anterior que te propongo, ya solo manejaras las celdas del tbody en la tabla con el siguiente script:

```
<script>
  function cargaGrid(){
      // variable donde almacenara el html de la tabla
      tbl = '';
      // si el datatable ya esta instanciado sobre la tabla
      // se detruye para que al recibir el nuevo contenido se rearme
      $('.tblHis').dataTable().fnDestroy();
      //vaciado de la tabla antes de insertar los nuevos resultados
      $('.tblHis tbody').empty();
      // peticion ajax
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "TU_POST_URL",
          //data: cad, // aqui si quieren enviar params
          success:function(data) {
              console.info(data);
              $.each(data.data,function(i,d){
                tbl += '<tr>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.nombres+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.apellidos+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.usuario+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.email+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.documento+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.celular+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.fechaIngreso+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.fechaRetiro+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.estado+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'+d.roll+'</td>';
                tbl += '<td>'; //aqui inicia la celda que contiene los botones
                tbl += '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn1" id="'+d.ID+'"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
                tbl += '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn2" id="'+d.ID+'"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
                tbl += '</td>'; // fin de celda de botones
                tbl += '</tr>';
              });
              // agragamos los resultados al tbl:
              $('.tblHis tbody').append(tbl);
              // configuracion de datatable:
              $('.tblHis').dataTable({
                  // ordenamiento por defecto de la segunda col.
                  "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
                  // aca puedes poner las demas configs. del datatable
              });
          }
      });
  }

  // accion para cargar la tbl
  cargaGrid();
</script>
```

saludo y espero te sirva de referencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias Nóe efectivamente aplique la solución adaptandola a mis necesidades y me funciono muchas gracias

Comment: Que bien! me ayudas a ponerle a mi respuesta como valida por favor, para hacerlo tienes que pulsar la palomita gris a lado izquierdo de mi respuesta. saludos.